# Picking any model from RandomizedSearchCV

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, model-selection, scikit-learn

I trained set of models using RandomizedSearchCV and picked the best using .best_estimator_ and then tested on my test set. However, I would like to check how any other model from the grid performed on the test set. Is it possible to do so and if yes, how can I do that?

Comment: Check out "cv_results_" and think about its relation with "best_estimator_"

Comment: Yeah, best_estimator_ is the model that achieved the highest mean score throught cv. I was just wondering if there is an easy way to pick for example 2nd best model and check its test score.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RandomizedSearchCV` discards the actual models it trains on each fold after evaluating them, so you won't be able to extract the fitted models from the output.

For `refit=True`, `RandomizedSearchCV` will pick the parameters that performed best on the validation sets and *re-train the model* with these parameters, this time on all observations. This is the model that you extract.
That would be inefficient to do for all parameter settings that were not selected, so `RandomizedSearchCV` does not retrain the second best model.

You could look at `_cv_results` to find the second best parameter settings and manually train the model with these parameters on all observations. Use method `set_params()` to set the parameters to the second or third best parameter set in `_cv_results_`.
I would not recommend this procedure to choose a set of parameters, since it negates the reason to do parameter selection using CV rather than your test set. You are likely overfit your parameter choice to the test data.